# Как найти нужную библиотеку для Android?

Tags: android

Планирую в своем приложении использовать разный функционал, который, как мне кажется, уже существует в виде библиотек, как то регистрация пользователей, определение координат, загрузка фотографий и т.д.

Где находится такое добро и как правильно отыскать требуемое?

Comment: Говорят, на https://google.com/ и https://github.com/ много интересного. Немного по теме - https://android-arsenal.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для регистрации пользователей попробуйте [FireBase](https://firebase.google.com/) от Google. Для работы с изображениями библиотека [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/). Еще есть группа "Вконтакте" там часто очень выкладывают интересные библиотеки и разные фишки, вот ссылка [Android Development](https://vk.com/andr_dev) Ну и как отметили выше на [GitHub](https://github.com/) в основном все можно найти.

Comment: Glide практически во всех сценариях предпочтительнее Picasso, просто пикассо разработана раньше и по инерции ее в первую очередь вспоминают

Answer (score 1):

Есть агрегатор, где организованы разделы, описания библиотек и другие удобства в поиске/ Все более-менее годное есть там:

[Android Arsenal](https://android-arsenal.com/)

Списки на Github с самым популярным и часто используемым:

[Must have](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Must-Have-libraries)
[Awesome library](https://github.com/wasabeef/awesome-android-libraries)

Самый большой выбор - поиск на Github. Для того, чтобы найти нужную библиотеку в поисковую строку пишите android и то, что требуется, например:

Найти [базы данных для Android](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=android%20database&type=)

Естественно, что это самая кропотливая работа и выбрать нужное сложнее, но и выбор намного больше. Так же, с недавних пор Github ввел теги и можно включить в поисковую строку тег [android], но не все разработчики библиотек указывают его.

В дайджестах, как [Android Weekly](http://androidweekly.net) всегда есть раздел с новыми и интересными библиотеками.