# Поиск библиотек для Android Studio (Java)

Tags: java, android-studio, поиск-библиотек

Как новичок прошу помощи в таком срамном вопросе как поиск библиотек в интернете. (не установка, а именно поиск). Я более-менее умею прописывать в gradle и добавлять скаченные библиотеки, но вот поиск у меня чрезвычайно не эффективен. Забивая названия необходимых библиотек гугл выдаёт много, но вообще не то или тупиковые пути, как в результате из кучи остаётся ноль. Заходя на такие сайты как java2s, findjar, maven ...я если и нахожу, то далеко не все нужные, а не все мне и даром не нужны. А когда дело доходит до сложных программ под типа видео чата, quickblox или hiworld, то найти все до одного 10 библиотек это вообще безисходно. Заходя на сайты с одноимёнными библиотекам названиями я вижу всё что угодно кроме Download (а я думал что download должен быть на главной странице красной кнопкой). Исща там в поисковике нужную библиотеку - она не выдаёт, то же блуждая по сайту: нахожу библиотеки или имплементации в градл, но не все. (Тут ещё проблема в незнании английского, чего уж скрывать). Вы скажите "Ну ты и тупой!" И будите правы, по этому я и прошу помочь.

Подитожу вопросы:

1) Как правильно "забить" в гугл название нужной подбиблиотеки в библиотеке. Например: com.quickblox.module.users.result.QBUserResult или указывать начиная только с выделенного в AS красным шрифтом?

2) Как правильно искать библиотеки на специализированый под эту библиотеку сайтах.

3) Можно ли как-то скачивать сразу всю-всю-всю библиотеку а не по отдельности? Например: com.quickblox ..... и все варианты после этого. (Размер скачки меня волнует во много раз меньше проблемы поиска).

Comment: вроде вся интеграция quikblox [по шагам расписана](https://quickblox.com/developers/Android#How_to:_add_SDK_to_IDE_and_connect_to_the_cloud) в официальной документации. Собирать библиотеки по частям обычно не требуется (если ее не писал какой то школьник криворукий, но такая библиотека и не нужна, думаю) - вероятнее всего вы неправильно ее интегрируете в проект. Смотрите документацию к библиотеке, как это сделать правильно. Вообще по поиску библиотек смотрите [этот вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/801695/177345)

Answer (score 5):

1) Искать нужно взяв в кавычки имя пакета:

```
"com.quickblox.module.users.result"
```

иначе поисковая система распознает точки как разделитель слов и найдет все слова, а не пакет целиком

2) В github'е можно искать по ключевым словам функционала с указанием языка программирования. В maven'е просто по названиям пакетов

3) Качать нужно всю либу (скачивание по частям либы нет такого понятия). Рекомендую прописывать зависимости в gradle через ключевое слово `implementation`, тогда зависимые части либы не будут конфликтовать друг с другом, но правда придется эти зависимости (если они нужны) отдельно прописывать.